# How do I optimize the DNS SOA Intervals & TTLs for my site?

Tags: web-hosting, dns

I am not sure if the DNS SOA Values & TTLs for our Records are optimal or not or even how to determine what is optimal. My hosting provider has recommended values only. Here are my current settings. So how do you determine what values are best for your website?

```
    DNS Zone:
    Refresh: 7200
    Retry: 2048
    Expire: 1048576
    Minimum: 21600

    DNS Records:
    example.com A - 600
    staging.example.com A - 3600
    ipv4.example.com A - 43200
    ftp.example.com CNAME -43200
    sm.example.com CNAME - 43200
    lg.example.com CNAME - 43200
    www.example.com CNAME - 43200
    example.com MX - 43200
```

Comment: Generally, these values are set by the host admins to be optimal for the environment based upon their experience. You can change them, however, short of really knowing DNS, I recommend not worrying about it.

Comment: Agree with @closetnoc -- it really depends on how often you plan to change your IP addresses, mail servers, name servers, etc... and, usually, that's not very often.

Comment: TTL values only really matter when looking at propagation of record updates.  If you're about to make changes, you can ask them to notch TTL values for individual records down to 10 minutes (3600) in case a quick back-out is needed, and then you can notch it back up to whatever value your DNS host suggests after you know there are no issues.  The lower the TTL value, the more queries your name server handles, so it's understandable to not leave a short interval in place.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should not worry too much about these things, as long as you are within the safety provided limits you can find on many sites or testing tools such as https://zonemaster.net/

`retry` and `expire` for example would only make sense to your current DNS hoster, they will depend a lot on its infrastructure and the way its nameservers are configured and running.